# How to use SortedMap interface or TreeMap in Java?

Tags: java, treemap, sortedmap

I have a

```
 Map<Float, MyObject>
```

What is the best way to keep the map sorted according to the float?

Is `SortedMap` or `TreeMap` the best answer?
How do I use it?

I only create the map once and replace the `MyObject` frequently using `myMap.put()` and `myMap.get()`.

Comment: But SortedMap is an interface. TreeMap implements SortedMap.

Comment: See the answer posted by `@user157196` here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: Look for Tom Jefferys' answer

Comment: FYI, [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) added in Java 6 supplants the older [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I would use `TreeMap`, which implements `SortedMap`. It is designed exactly for that.

Example:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

// Add Items to the TreeMap
map.put(1, "One");
map.put(2, "Two");
map.put(3, "Three");

// Iterate over them
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " => " + entry.getValue());
}
```

See the [Java tutorial page for SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/sorted-map.html).
And [here a list of tutorials](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/0320__TreeMap.htm) related to TreeMap.

Comment: Why do you do `new Integer(n)` instead of just the bare integer?

Comment: @Adam_G No special reason, I guess that when I wrote this answer I was not used to auto-boxing (?).

Answer (score 54):

A TreeMap is probably the most straightforward way of doing this.  You use it exactly like a normal Map. i.e.

```
Map<Float,String> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Float,MyObject>();
// Put some values in it
mySortedMap.put(1.0f,"One");
mySortedMap.put(0.0f,"Zero");
mySortedMap.put(3.0f,"Three");

// Iterate through it and it'll be in order!
for(Map.Entry<Float,String> entry : mySortedMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
} // outputs Zero One Three
```

It's worth taking a look at the API docs, http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html to see what else you can do with it.

Answer (score 21):

You can use TreeMap which internally implements the SortedMap below is the example

**Sorting by ascending ordering :**

```
  Map<Float, String> ascsortedMAP = new TreeMap<Float, String>();

  ascsortedMAP.put(8f, "name8");
  ascsortedMAP.put(5f, "name5");
  ascsortedMAP.put(15f, "name15");
  ascsortedMAP.put(35f, "name35");
  ascsortedMAP.put(44f, "name44");
  ascsortedMAP.put(7f, "name7");
  ascsortedMAP.put(6f, "name6");

  for (Entry<Float, String> mapData : ascsortedMAP.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + mapData.getKey() + "Value : " + mapData.getValue());
  }
```

**Sorting by descending ordering :**

If you always want this create the map to use descending order in general, if you only need it once create a TreeMap with descending order and put all the data from the original map in.

```
  // Create the map and provide the comparator as a argument
  Map<Float, String> dscsortedMAP = new TreeMap<Float, String>(new Comparator<Float>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Float o1, Float o2) {
      return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
  });
  dscsortedMAP.putAll(ascsortedMAP);
```

for further information about SortedMAP read http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/treemap/java-sorted-map-example/

Comment: I'd prefer this answer as it's making  what  the SortedMap was  designed  for by using the Comparator

Answer (score 3):

TreeMap, which is an implementation of the SortedMap interface, would work.

> How do I use it ?

```
Map<Float, MyObject> map = new TreeMap<Float, MyObject>();
```

Answer (score 2):

`TreeMap` sorts by the key natural ordering. The keys should implement `Comparable` or be compatible with a `Comparator` (if you passed one instance to constructor). In you case, `Float` already implements `Comparable` so you don't have to do anything special.

You can call `keySet` to retrieve all the keys in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use either of the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) implementations bundled with Java 6 and later that implement [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) (the successor to [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html)):

- Use [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) if running single-threaded, or if the map is to be read-only across threads after first being populated.
- Use [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) if manipulating the map across threads.

## `NavigableMap`

FYI, the [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface was succeeded by the [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface.

You would only need to use `SortedMap` if using 3rd-party implementations that have not yet declared their support of `NavigableMap`. Of the maps bundled with Java, both of the implementations that implement `SortedMap` also implement `NavigableMap`.

## Interface versus concrete class

> s SortedMap the best answer? TreeMap?

As others mentioned, `SortedMap` is an interface while `TreeMap` is one of multiple implementations of that interface (and of the more recent `NavigableMap`.

Having an interface allows you to write code that uses the map without breaking if you later decide to switch between implementations.

```
NavigableMap< Employee , Project > currentAssignments = new TreeSet<>() ;
currentAssignments.put( alice , writeAdCopyProject ) ; 
currentAssignments.put( bob , setUpNewVendorsProject ) ;
```

This code still works if later change implementations. Perhaps you later need a map that supports concurrency for use across threads. Change that declaration to:

```
NavigableMap< Employee , Project > currentAssignments = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>() ;
```

…and the rest of your code using that map continues to work.

## Choosing implementation

There are ten implementations of `Map` bundled with Java 11. And more implementations provided by 3rd parties such as [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava).

Here is a graphic table I made highlighting the various features of each. Notice that two of the bundled implementations keep the keys in sorted order by examining the key’s content. Also, `EnumMap` keeps its keys in the order of the objects defined on that enum. Lastly, the `LinkedHashMap` remembers original insertion order.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TreeMap` class for this purpose which implements the `SortedMap` interface.

The class `TreeMap` implements the `NavigableMap` interface which extends the `SortedMap` interface.

This will have the effect that all the keys will be ordered according to their implementation of their `Comparable` interface.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

// Add Items to the TreeMap
map.put(9999, "foo");
map.put(23432, "bar");
map.put(6, "foobar");
map.put(12, "baz");
```

The keys are now automatically in sorted order. When we iterate over them we get the following:

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("key: " + k));

// output:
// key: 6
// key: 12
// key: 9999
// key: 23432
```

Because `TreeMap` elements are required to be ordered the Objects which are used as a key need to have a implementation of the `Comparable` interface. For example the following code will throw a runtime error:

```
class Human{}
Map<Human, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

// Following throws a exception:
// Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
// class Example$1Human cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable 
map.put(new Human(), "baz");
```