# Android sort a Hashmap in arraylist

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, hashmap

I am fetching JSON Data from server and able to parse JSON Data by code.
now storing it in hashmap and then adding to arraylist and displaying in listview everything
seems working fine.

```
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                         map.put(Constants.KEY_REFERENCE,p.reference);                      map.put(Constants.KEY_NAME, p.name);
map.put("distance","p.distance");
ArrayListItems.add(map);
```

Now,When i display the data in listview it works fine ,but now i want to sort the distance in ascending order ,with least starting from top .
Any help will be appreciated .Thanks in advance

now i am able to sort but there is something wrong with the distance when i display it shows
1.23,
1.45,
2.39,
3.56,
and then it shows 
0.38,
0.56.

Its not sorting for values starting with 0

So please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property) with custom object == `HashMap<String, String>` and "property" == `HashMap<String, String>.get("propertyName")` ...

Comment: use SortedMap instead of Map.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427758/java-how-to-use-sortedmap and http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/sortedmap.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at `Collections.sort();` and how you can use the `Comparable` interface to sort the `HashMap` (by overriding the `compare()` method). The following [article](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-a-map-in-java/) is quite useful, because if I am not mistaken, there are two distinct ways in which you can sort a HashMap; one by it's keys and the other by it's values.