# Adding a SimpleEntry to a SortedMap

Tags: java, eclipse, dictionary, sortedmap

I wanted to create a variable I can iterate and sort later containing a "Move" and a double value. I thought my best shot would be the SortedMap with an integer (I read I need some kind of comparator) and an Entry containing my actual data. I have this method

```
    public SortedMap<Integer, Entry<Move, Double>> listFishMoves(Field fishField) {
    ArrayList<Move> fishMoves = getFishMoves(fishField);
    SortedMap<Integer, SimpleEntry<Move, Double>> moveMap = new SortedMap<Integer, SimpleEntry<Move, Double>>();
    int i = 0;
    for (Move move : fishMoves) {
        double turnValue = getMoveValue(move);
        moveMap.put(i, new SimpleEntry(move, turnValue));
        i++;
    }
}
```

My Problem is that I get an error in line 3 when initializing the SortedMap (Cannot instantiate the type SortedMap>).
I also get 2 warnings when adding the new SimpleEntry:
1. Type safety: The expression of type AbstractMap.SimpleEntry needs unchecked conversion to conform to AbstractMap.SimpleEntry
2. Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
Type safety: The expression of type AbstractMap.SimpleEntry needs unchecked conversion to conform to AbstractMap.SimpleEntry

I am totally new to Maps and would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: See also: [*How to use SortedMap interface in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7427758/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Interface versus Implementation

Your problem is that [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) is an [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)#Software_interfaces_in_object-oriented_languages) - you cannot instantiate it. You need to select an implementation that suits your need.

For instance, you could use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

```
SortedMap<Integer, SimpleEntry<Move, Double>> moveMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

For the warning, change your line to

```
moveMap.put(i, new SimpleEntry<>(move, turnValue));
```

Look for the words “interface”, “class”, and “implementing” when reading the [JavaDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc).

[image]

Comment: looks like i missed that when reading the documentation, thank you!