# When should I sort Map elements in Java?

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap, treemap

I have an excel file that keeps user role and permission as shown below (some fields are omitted for brevity):

```
User Role | Permission Uuid    
----------|----------------                     
0         | a465433f... 
0         | 43db5a33...
1         | 610e9040... 
0         | 94e85bef... 
1         | 34e85f32...
```

I am reading an excel file row by row and need to pass a request as shown below to create imported data:

```
public class PermissionRequest {
    private UserRole userRole;
    private List<UUID> permissionUuidList;
}
```

I think that I need to map each Permission Uuid by User Role and for this reason I tried to use `Map<Integer, List<UUID>>` as shown below:

```
Map<Integer, List<UUID>> userRolePermissionMap = new HashMap<>();
userRolePermissionMap.put(Integer.parseInt(cellList.get(USER_ROLE)),
    Collections.singletonList(UUID.fromString(cellList.get(PERMISSON_UUID))));
```

But I think it it not correct. So, **as the User Role is not sorted in the excel file**, should I need a sort or grouping by User Role and then send `PermissionRequest` to the repository in a loop for create operation? Or should I use a `TreeMap` for this purpose? If so, how can I use?

Comment: `HashMap` isn't sorted. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for - you do not need to sort inputs to create hashmap with proper mappings, even if you would add `0` then `1` then `0` then `1` and so on, everything will go to the proper bucket. However if you need to sort uuids on a list then you need to provide sorting by yourself

Comment: @m.antkowicz I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427758/how-to-use-sortedmap-interface-in-java) approach, but it does not sort by User Role. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap` does not guarantee the sorted order, `TreeMap` is sorted by keys (`UserRole` in this case) and additionally, the lists of UUIDs can be sorted (if necessary).

However, the code above uses `Collections.singletonList` which is not correct because such list is immutable and can contain only one UUID.

A concise implementation using Java Stream API [`Collectors.groupingBy` with `Supplier<Map>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) may look as follows assuming that there is a list of `cellList` objects representing rows:

```java
Map<Integer, List<UUID>> userRolePermissionMap =
        rowsList.stream() // Stream<Row> 
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    cellList -> Integer.parseInt(cellList.get(USER_ROLE)),
                    TreeMap::new, // supplier of sorted map
                    Collectors.mapping(
                        cellList -> UUID.fromString(cellList.get(PERMISSON_UUID)),
                        Collectors.toList())
                ));
```

The loop-based implementation using [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) may be as follows (an empty list is created if a roleId key is missing and the UUID is added to the list of UUIDs):

```java
Map<Integer, List<UUID>> userRolePermissionMap = new TreeMap<>();

for (List<Cell> cellList : rowList) {
    userRolePermissionMap.computeIfAbsent(
        Integer.parseInt(cellList.get(USER_ROLE)),
        k -> new ArrayList<UUID>()
    )  // mutable List<UUID> is returned
    .add(UUID.fromString(cellList.get(PERMISSON_UUID)));
}
```

Comment: Perfect!... Thanks a lot.